# Dynamically updating bokeh server plot from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, bokeh

I'm trying to create a plot of some data which sits within a Pandas dataframe saved into an HDF5 file. I'd like to share this plot with colleagues within my organisation via a link, and I'd like it to dynamically update every 30 mins (the dataframe within the HDF5 file is updated with new data every 30 mins).

Using the following code, I am able to put the plot out onto Bokeh Server. However, I'm not sure how to make it update dynamically, nor exactly how to make the plot available to colleagues. Does anyone have any pointers?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, output_server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore

store = pd.HDFStore('storage.h5')
df = pd.DataFrame(store['d1'])
df = df.rename_axis('Time')
df.fillna(0)

output_server("output")

ds = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(width=800, height=800, x_axis_type='datetime', title="PUE", x_axis_label='Time', y_axis_label='PUE')
p.line(source=ds,x='Time',y='PUE', line_width=2)
show(p)
```